# .NET Core MVC app runs locally but not in container (System.DirectoryServices.Protocols not supported)

Tags: docker, .net-core

We created an application using Visual Studio 2017's project tamplate ".NET Core Web Application (Model-View-Controller)", selecting "Change Authentication->Individual User Accounts"

We then developed the application and were getting read to push our first container.

After a publish to folder, we tested inside the publish folder by running

```
dotnet nameof.dll
```

All tests passed.  Snippet from `docker log`:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: \publish
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started.  Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

So far so good.

We then tried building a simple container with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2
WORKDIR app
EXPOSE 80
COPY  publish .
CMD ["dotnet", "nameof.dll"]
```

The site came up but with a warning.

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {8f452e97-17ae-45cb-bcfb-d97a81ce1199} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Other than that, everything looked fine.  Browsed to the site.  Looking good.

When we tried to log in this exception is thrown:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols is not supported on this platform.
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols is not supported on this platform.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryIdentifier..ctor()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapDirectoryIdentifier..ctor(String server)
   at CycleMenu.Controllers.AccountController.<Login>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\gg\AramarkCycleMenu\src\CycleMenu\CycleMenu\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 78
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Clearly something is missing from the docker image, but if it's not in the publish folder, where is it?  How could this work outside the container but not inside?

We tried

- building with different base images
- Linux and Windows containers
- Adding Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility (I lost the link to the article that guided us to do that)
- banging our heads against the wall.

According to this discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089 `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` was originally not included in .NET Core, but now it is (Nov 2017).  Could it be the images on docker hub aren't up to date yet, and that's why we're getting "...not supported on this platform"?

Running `dotnet --version` returns 2.1.4 both inside the container and outside.

Can you provide any help or insight how to get past this error and get the otherwise working code correctly into a docker image?

Edit to answer: Running Docker for Windows on Windows 10

Comment: What OS is running on the container host?

Comment: @DavidG: added answer

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue using Nuget package `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` version `4.6.0` in a dotnet core 3.0 docker container based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0`.

But, as we can see in the issue you refereed to there will be no support for other platforms than Windows: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089#issuecomment-373219911

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has added `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` support for Linux and MacOS. Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23944